# Load Differential data using SSIS

Tags: ssis

Hi I have around 1000 million record in production Table and around 1500 million record in Staging table,Here I need to compare staging data with production data if any new record then insert it and if there are some changes on record then update the column or insert a new column.So what is the best approach for this condition?Please suggest.

Comment: Are they on the same SQL Server?

Comment: production and staging database on different sql server version 2008

Comment: How frequently will you be be performing this? Do you have the option to add triggers to the source system?

Comment: We are doing first time this task and in future we need to perform same thing 4 times in a year.We didn't have to add triggers option in source system.

Comment: Are you just trying to get an exact copy of the source table or are there some transformations? Basically you haven't given any detail in your question that's why I keep asking questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get a copy of a table from one database to another four times a year, one way is to simply truncate and reload the target table. Don't mess around trying to update individual rows, it's often quicker to delete the lot and reload them.

You need to do some analysis and see if there is any field you can use in the source to reliably load a subset of data. For example if there is a 'created date' on the record you can use that just load the data created in the last three months data (instead of all of it)

If you add some more info then we can be more specific about a solution.

i.e.

-This has to be fast but we have lots of disk space
-This must be simple to maintain and can take a day to load

Also... I assume the source and target is SQL Server? If so is it the Enterprise edition?